# Is it possible to find incoming IP addresses in Google Container Engine cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

My nginx access log deployed in a GKE Kubernetes cluster (with type LoadBalancer Kubernetes service) shows internal IPs instead of real visitor IP.

Is there a way to find real IPs anywhere? maybe some log file provided by GKE/Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the `type: LoadBalancer` service does a double hop. The external request is balanced among all the cluster's nodes, and then kube-proxy balances amongst the actual service backends.

kube-proxy NATs the request. E.g. a client request from `1.2.3.4` to your external load balancer at `100.99.98.97` gets NATed in the node to `10.128.0.1->10.100.0.123` (node's private IP to pod's cluster IP). So the "src ip" you see in the backend is actually the private IP of the node.

There is a [feature planned](https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/27) with a corresponding [design proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/30105) for preservation of client IPs of LoadBalancer services.

Comment: And kube-proxy has no log of the incoming requests before it nats things? :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [real IP module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) for nginx.

Pass your internal GKE net as a `set_real_ip_from` directive and you'll see the real client IP in your logs:

> set_real_ip_from  192.168.1.0/24;

Typically you would add to the nginx configuration:

1. *The load balancers IP*
   i.e. the IP that you see in your logs instead of the real client IP currently
2. *The kubernetes network*
   i.e. the subnet your *Pods* are in, the "Docker subnet"

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seems to work.
I added these directives after `http {` on nginx

  set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
  set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.0/24;
  set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
  real_ip_recursive on;

Comment: I updated my answer. Your subnets are most likely wrong. Could you give more details about your Pod network? Your config should match reality. 127.0.0.1 doesn't make much sense here, unless you actually have a proxy running in your Pods together with another app.

Comment: I tried to test it with accepting all ip: `set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;` but still not seeing client IP on the logs

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the header is set by the GCE load balancer? Also you shouldn't define 0.0.0.0/0 because this effectively includes the client network. Once again without any logs or information about your networks it's hard to make any other suggestion.

Comment: On the logs, queries comes from: 10.142.0.2, 10.142.0.3, 10.142.0.6
So I changed the set_real_ip_from to `10.142.0.0/24`
But still getting these IP on my nginx logs. This nginx server is behind a GCE LB, but I'm not sure if there's any other intermediary.

Comment: Then I'm quite sure the `X-Forwarded-For` header is missing. You can try to tune the nginx log format to include request headers and verify that theory. There might be a way to activate it on the GCE LB. Another intermediary can be the Docker daemon, which usually NATs incoming traffic, so your kubernetes internal network should also be declared inside the nginx configuration (check the IP and netmask of the br0 interface on your nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Adding of these lines to my nginx.conf HTTP block fixed this issue for me and real visitor IPs started displaying in Stackdriver LogViewer:

```
http {
...
real_ip_recursive on;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
set_real_ip_from 192.168.0.0/24;
set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
...
}
```

I'm a happy camper :)